# Serialize a object for country dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a table of flags which I get simply as this.

```
public void GetFlags()
{
        var flags = _context.Flags.ToList();
        ViewBag.CountryFlags = flags;
}
```

I want to place it in a view bag but I need it in this format

```
var isoCountries = [
        { id: 1, flag: 'af', country  : 'Afghanistan' },
        { id: 2, flag: 'ax', country  : 'Aland Islands' },
        { id: 3, flag: 'al', country  : 'Albania' },
        { id: 4, flag: 'dz', country  : 'Algeria' },
        { id: 5, flag: 'as', country  : 'American Samoa' },
        { id: 6, flag: 'ad', country  : 'Andorra' },
        { id: 7, flag: 'ao', country  : 'Angola' },
        { id: 8, flag: 'ai', country  : 'Anguilla' }
]
```

How would I ensure that my class is encoded properly I know I should have the same elements as wanted in iso countries but how do I serialize, is correctly.

**Flags class**

```
public class Flags {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string flag { get; set; }
    public string country  { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I produce the flag in the dropdown.

```
<Script>

 $(function () {
    //Initialize Select2 Elements
    //$('.select2').select2()
    var isoCountries = @ViewBag.CountryFlags; 

    function formatCountry(country) {
        if (!country.id) { return country.text; }
        var $country = $(
            '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-' + country.Flag + ' flag-icon-squared"></span>' +
            '<span class="flag-text">' + country.Country + "</span>"
        );
        return $country;
    };

    //Assuming you have a select element with name country
    // e.g. <select name="name"></select>
    $("[id='CountryOfBirth']").select2({
        placeholder: "Please Select a country",
        templateResult: formatCountry,
        data: isoCountries
    });

      $('#CountryOfBirth').trigger('change');

});
</script>
```

What I tried

```
public void GetFlags() {
   var flags = _context.Flags.ToList();
   var isoCountires = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(flags);
   ViewBag.CountryFlags = isoCountires;
 }
```

I also tried using this as I noticed by json was having html encoding on it

```
 var isoCountries = { json : "@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@ViewBag.CountryFlags))" };
```

But its still not in the right format to produce the results of above.

Comment: We need to know the type of the flags inside _context.  Please include that declaration in your question.  It probably starts with `class Flag`.  You will probably be able to solve your problem quite simply using the Linq `Select` method.

Comment: This needs more detail.  Help me reproduce your results.

Comment: @Wyck please see above

Comment: @JoelFan added more detail sorry about that

Comment: I think you mean [serialize](https://www.bing.com/search?q=define+serialize), not [sterilize](https://www.bing.com/search?q=define+sterilize), but I'm not sure.

Comment: @HereticMonkey made the adjustment u are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change it like this:

```
var isoCountries = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.CountryFlags)');
```

With the GetFlags method:

```
public void GetFlags() {
    var flags = _context.Flags.ToList();
    var isoCountires = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(flags);
    ViewBag.CountryFlags = isoCountires;
}
```